# can't get mysql module to work with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am compleeeeetly new to Node js and wanted to start my very first project to get used to it. I am using the excess framework.

I found some nice mysql module which was easily downloaded and installed. The module is correctly placed in the modules folder.

I tried to call it in my app.js file like that:

```
...
var mysql = require('mysql');
...
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '27sparks&&55',
  database : 'react'
});
connection.connect();
app.locals.mysql = connection;

connection.query('SELECT * FROM comment', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(rows);
});

connection.end();
```

When I try to run the www in the /bin directory with this command : `node www` to start my localhost project I now get following error in the terminal:

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/nodeschool/learn/app.js:79
  if (err) throw err;
           ^

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/nodeschool/learn/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/nodeschool/learn/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/nodeschool/learn/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:123:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/nodeschool/learn/app.js:75:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting feedback from the connect line (code taken from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#establishing-connections)) :

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
```

Also, try setting the port to 3306 manually, even though it defaults to it.

Stupid questions worth asking : is your MySQL instance up and running ? Is it listening on the good port ? Is the password correct ?

Comment: yea its up and running ^^

Comment: I tried your code and get the same error as before :)

Answer (score 0):

you are probably trying to connect to the wrong socket
add a `socketPath` to your create connection option object like this

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '27sparks&&55',
  database : 'react',
  socketPath : 'path/to/your/mysqlsocket' // /*example: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock on ubuntu*/
});
```

Comment: How can I find the socket path ? 
I am running mysql on Xampp

Comment: try /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: well is your mysql socket really located in the path I gave you? did you check?

Comment: Yes. You guessed pretty good. It's exactly where you wrote. Along with my custom created databases which I use for different php projects